# How to reference/iterate multiple lists in Python

Tags: python, list

All the responses I've found to this question are either short circuited or not purely pythonic.

If I have several lists:

```
audcad = ["audcad",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
audchf = ["audchf",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
audjpy = ["audjpy",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

ccys = ["audcad", "audchf", "audjpy"]
```

The following code should clarify my intention:

```
for ccy in ccys:
    ccy[13] += 10
```

should result in:

```
audcad = ["audcad",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]
audchf = ["audchf",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]
audjpy = ["audjpy",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10]
```

because I'm referencing using a string object:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

I don't want to use numpy for this because I'm deploying to a server that I want to install as little as possible, so the code needs to be as pythonic as possible.  How can I loop over an arbitrary list to populate and read specific elements in each?

I'm thinking a 2D object like an list of arrays may be a better solution, but I would still need how to iterate over the object without having to use large if statements and a separate list of array names (spot the hacky SA).

Comment: So in short you want to access a list based on a string of its name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list `ccys` should contain the other list variables themselves (as shallow copies), not their names as strings

```
ccys = [audcad, audchf, audjpy]
```

Then your code will work fine

```
for ccy in ccys:
    ccy[13] += 10

>>> audcad
['audcad', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
>>> audchf
['audchf', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
>>> audjpy
['audjpy', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do -

```
ccys = ["audcad", "audchf", "audjpy"]
```

You are putting strings (like `"audcad"`) in the list, that does not put the lists in `ccys` list. To put the lists there you should do -

```
ccys = [audcad, audchf, audjpy]
```

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you actually have to use strings, you could use locals:

```
audcad = ["audcad",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
audchf = ["audchf",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
audjpy = ["audjpy",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

ccys = ["audcad", "audchf", "audjpy"]

for ccy in ccys:
    locals()[ccy][13] += 10
```

If you want to be accessing by name then you might be a well create a dict from the lists, using the first element as the name:

```
 dct = {l[0]: l for l in (audcad,audjpy,audchf)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
for ccy in ccys:
    filter(lambda o: o[0] == ccy, locals())[0][13] += 10
```

It basically gets the list where the first element is equal to the current `ccy` in each iteration of the `for` loop.